# Getting data using ruby and db call

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to retrieve the ProductType from a table on our database. I am a relative novice when it comes to ruby and am trying to use pre-existing code as a basis for this. I have tried to use a piece of code with a similar purpose but cant seem to get it working.

```
def load_account_type
  @accounttypes = @db.call('IBAccountList', @id).map do |accounttype|
    {accounttype: accounttype['ProductTypeID']}
  end
end
```

The IBAccountList is a stored procedure:

```
SELECT ac.CUAccountID, ac.AccountNumber, ac.BalanceDate, p.Description, ac.ParentAccountID, p.ProductTypeID,
    CASE p.ProductTypeID WHEN 1 THEN 
        dbo._Balance(ac.DRAmount, ac.CRAmount) * -1 
    ELSE 
        dbo._Balance(ac.DRAmount, ac.CRAmount) 
    END AS Balance, 
    CASE p.ProductTypeID WHEN 1 THEN 
        NULL 
    ELSE (
        SELECT dbo._Balance(intr.DRAmount, intr.CRAmount) 
        FROM CUAccount intr
        WHERE intr.ParentAccountID = ac.CUAccountID
    ) 
    END AS Interest  
    FROM CUAccount ac
    INNER JOIN CUProduct p ON ac.ProductID = p.ProductID 
    WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID AND
    ac.Active = 1 AND
    ac.ParentAccountID IS NULL 
    ORDER BY ac.AccountNumber
```

Could someone help to explain what this code would do as I am at a loss. Any further information required just let me know. Thanks!

Comment: when you say you 'can't get it working' - what do you mean by that?  is there an error?  is what you've put in the post the code that is working or the  code that is failing?

Comment: @dax as in it wont return anything. I'm really not that experienced with ruby so not sure it will work but just seeking guidance as to how i should do it.